# Script to perform like a search macro in a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, vba

I use a macro in an Excel spreadsheet that allows me to type in one or multiple words and search the spreadsheet for those words.  Each row of the spreadsheet that contains those words is copied over to sheet 2 of the spreadsheet. (The spreadsheet is basically a large list of inventory at my  work place. So, for example, if I wanted to search our inventory for all 'red widgets', I can type the word red, and the word widget into the search field and on sheet 2 of the spreadsheet, a list of all of our red widgets would appear (even those listed as "widget red")). Could a script in Google sheets do the same thing? I would really like to use Google sheets instead of Excel for this.

Comment: [Here](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gooscript) would be the best place to start.  There is no easy way to do this as they are two different languages.  It would be like trying to converse in Spanish to someone who only speaks Arabic.

Comment: Thanks so much, I am looking into this now to try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

A Google Apps Script can definitely do this. You would likely be best off starting from scratch rather than working from your Excel Macro code.

There are a few options for how you could set this up, but off the top of my head I would approach it like this:

1. Add a custom menu to the sheet, with "find & copy" menu entry
2. Pop up a a simple dialog using HtmlService, where the user enters the
   search term.
3. On submission, retrieve all rows from Sheet1
4. Loop over the rows and search for your term in one or more columns
5. copy matching rows to a new array
6. write the array of matches to a new sheet.

See the extending sheets overview here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

html service here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

and function references for these services here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that. I am looking into these links now.